# Missing Settings Directory in Whisker Menu

Tags: xubuntu, whisker, desktop-directories

On Xubuntu (Ubuntu 14.04+ `xubuntu-desktop`) Settings Directory is missing in Whisker Menu. Below is Screen-shot:

[image]

**How do I reset/restore/fix in Whisker Menu?**

---

Additional Info:

```
$ cat /usr/share/desktop-directories/xfce-settings.directory
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Directory
Icon=preferences-desktop
Name=Settings
Comment=Desktop and system settings applications

$ cat /usr/share/desktop-directories/Settings.directory
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Preferences
Comment=Personal preferences
Icon=preferences-desktop
Type=Directory
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=gnome-menus-3.0
```

Comment: This was reported as a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xubuntu-default-settings/+bug/1310264

Comment: @BrunoNova I've upgraded `xfce4-whiskermenu-plugin` to version 1.4.0 but problem is still exist.

Comment: The bug is still not fixed in Trusty. I don't know about Utopic. Maybe you should comment on the bug report. By the way, [this](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/utopic/xubuntu-default-settings/utopic/revision/147/etc/xdg/xdg-xubuntu/menus/xfce-applications.menu) seems to be the change that fixes the issue, in case you want to fix it yourself.

Comment: @BrunoNova Ok. I revised **file changes** and now solved {Also Included  Answer}

Comment: Per [Oli on bug reports](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/11718/when-is-a-bug-a-bug/11719#11719) I think it would be best to just leave this open for now.

Comment: @Seth ok. I just retracted my close vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes according to [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xubuntu-default-settings/+bug/1310264) bug, I added following line in: `/etc/xdg/xdg-xubuntu/menus/xfce-applications.menu` (**from [this](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/utopic/xubuntu-default-settings/utopic/view/147/etc/xdg/xdg-xubuntu/menus/xfce-applications.menu) revision**)

```
<Menu>
        <Name>Settings</Name>
        <Directory>xfce-settings.directory</Directory>
        <Include>
            <Category>Settings</Category>
        </Include>
        <Exclude>
            <Or>
                <Filename>exo-mail-reader.desktop</Filename>
                <Filename>exo-web-browser.desktop</Filename>
            </Or>
        </Exclude>

        <Layout>
            <Filename>xfce-settings-manager.desktop</Filename>
            <Separator/>
            <Merge type="all"/>
        </Layout>
    </Menu>
```

Now Settings Directory is Available:

[image: Whisker Settings]

---

<sup>Thank-you to @BrunoNova for co-operation by comments</sup>